# Duplicate identical entries in lightdm on 17.10

Tags: gnome, login, 17.10, lightdm

I recently updated from 16.04 to 17.10, and noticed that now on the lightdm login screen I have multiple duplicate entries, some of which differ only by the icon:

[image]

What is causing this? And what is the difference between the different duplicate entries?

In particular, I noticed that I can successfully login using the *GNOME on Xorg* option that is highlighted in the photo above, but if I try to login with the other one I cannot get past the login process (each time I login I get a black screen and then I am sent back to the login page).

Answer (score 3):

Same here, after install enlightenment I got it duplicate in lightdm.
The installation put `.desktop` files in

```
/usr/share/wayland-sessions
```

and

```
/usr/share/xsessions
```

Since I do not use Wayland, I just move the `.desktop` files to `.backup`

```
cd /usr/share/wayland-sessions/
for f in *.desktop; do  mv -- "$f" "${f%.desktop}.backup"; done
```

That's my case. If you are using Wayland rename the `.desktop` files in `xsessions`.

Check what type of session you are using, after a successful login type:

```
loginctl
```

to get the session ID.

To get the Type (x11 or wayland):

```
loginctl show-session "SESSION-ID" -p Type
```

eg:

```
$ loginctl show-session c2 -p Type
Type=x11
```

Comment: Thank you! long time away from console. ;)
Here it works beacause there is only one file (enlightenment.desktop) and his name is now *.backup hehe
Just edit the answer using a "for" for the job.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue after upgrading from 17.04 to 17.10. Duplicate Gnome on Xorg, Duplicate Ubuntu on Xorg. No duplicate of Xubuntu, though.